# Ошибка при запуске первого проекта Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

После установки Android Studio, я попыталась запустить новый проект, но он не запустился и вывел ошибку "Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
" (см. скрин). Подскажите как это можно исправить?
PS на сайте было написано версия "4.2.2 for Windows 64-bit (931 MiB)"
PPS до этого работала с этим приложением только на учебе и не устанавливала его самостоятельно, пожалуйста помогите!!
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В окне внизу переключитесь на MyApplication2 и приведите полный текст ошибки оттуда.

Comment: прошу прощения, проблема оказалась пустяковой (просто grandl последний поставила и все заработало)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема решена - просто gradle последний поставила и все заработало